# Most efficient way to print all variations of a String?

Tags: java, arrays, string

If I have a 7 word String (`I like it when it rains hard`) and I want to print every variation of it that is

- a) Greater than two words

and

- b) Not changing the original word order.

How best to do that? I'll print below what my end-goal is :

```
 I like it when it rains hard 
 I like it when it rains 
 I like it when it 
 I like it when 
 I like it 
 I like 
 like it when it rains hard 
 like it when it rains 
 like it when it 
 like it when 
 like it 
 it when it rains hard 
 it when it rains 
 it when it 
 it when 
 when it rains hard 
 when it rains 
 when it 
 it rains hard 
 it rains 
 rains hard
```

My Program is almost achieving that but not quite and I wonder if there is a smarter way of tackling it than what I have... ?

```
//Strings.java
//Goal: to print out each possible version of data without changing the original   
//order and without printing strings of less than 2 words.

public class Strings  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

  String var = " ";
  String data = "I like it when it rains hard";

  String [] s = data.split(" ");

  for (int i = 0 ; i <= s.length-1 ; i++)  {  //inner

    for (int j = s.length-1 ; j >= 1 ; j--)  {  //outer

      for ( int num = i ; num <= j ; num++)  {  

          var += s[num] + " ";        
      }
       System.out.println(var);
       var = " ";
    }     
  }


  }
}
```

Comment: Most efficient in regards to what? CPU usage? Memory usage? Cookie consumption?

Comment: You state that your solution is "not quite" complete. Why is your current solution not working as you expect?

Comment: @TheLostMind: yeah, but it could be stated in the question in that case I would think, instead of having the readers guess. :-)

Comment: How about using a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @Patrick because it starts printing a few blank lines once it gets near the end around 'it rains hard' 'rains hard'. And also it satisfies the no more than two words part for the first six lines of output but after that it starts printing single words each time too

Comment: @Patrick in regards to cpu usage and readibility of the code. I thought there might be a method in Java I hadnt found that could help

Comment: Your solution doesn't print **all** combinations of your words. For example, `I it it hard` and `I when hard` are ignored. Try splitting int into bits to get all combinations (as suggested below) or correct the description of your task.

Comment: This is called a [**permuted index**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permuted_index) (dealing with several sentences), normally shown in three columns: part before word, ordered word, remaining part, with sort order 2, 1, 3 (often also 2, 3, 1). For every word in the sentence, the line appears in the index.

Comment: @Aivean I dont want ALL combinations in that sense. I know youre correct there but unfortunately I cant put in to words exactly what I mean in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just modify the outer line like this

`for (int j = s.length - 1; j > i; j--) {  //outer`

do you also want to get out of sequence words? like
"I like it when it" -> "I like when" ?

Comment: No. I dont want out of sequence words. thanks for the code :D

Answer (score 0):

If the number of words in your sentence is *n*, collect all numbers from *3* below *2<sup>n</sup>* where the count of bits (`logcount`) is at least 2.

For each such number, viewed as a bit field, collect the words where the bit at that position is 1 into a new sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Just change one thing, in second *for* loop **j** should go to **(i+1)** means **j>=(i+1)**,

```
 public class Strings  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

  String var = " ";
  String data = "I like it when it rains hard";

  String [] s = data.split(" ");

  for (int i = 0 ; i <= s.length-1 ; i++)  {  //inner

    for (int j = s.length-1 ; j >= i+1 ; j--)  {  //outer

      for ( int num = i ; num <= j ; num++)  {  

          var += s[num] + " ";        
      }
       System.out.println(var);
       var = " ";
    }     
  }


  }
}
```

And you get same output as you wanted

```
 I like it when it rains hard 
 I like it when it rains 
 I like it when it 
 I like it when 
 I like it 
 I like 
 like it when it rains hard 
 like it when it rains 
 like it when it 
 like it when 
 like it 
 it when it rains hard 
 it when it rains 
 it when it 
 it when 
 when it rains hard 
 when it rains 
 when it 
 it rains hard 
 it rains 
 rains hard
```

Answer (score 0):

It prints the pattern, however I doubt its complexity.

```
    String line = "I like it when it rains hard";
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        int len = tokens.length;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; len--) {
            System.out.print(tokens[i] + " ");
            for (int k = j; k < len; k++) {
                System.out.print(tokens[k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```